# Как деактивировать предыдущую нажатую ToggleButton?

Tags: android, kotlin

У меня есть 5 ToggleButton, которые фильтруют отображаемые метки на карте по id(filterValues).
Суть такая, если нажать на кнопку которая выводит 17 объектов, она выведет 17 объектов, если нажать другую кнопку которая выводит 5 объектов, выведутся 5 объектов, но прошлая нажатая кнопка останется активированной(хоть и никак не влияет на вывод меток). Так вот, как исправить данное поведение? Чтобы ToggleButton работали как будто RadioButton в группе, то есть только одна кнопка может быть активирована из всех.
RadioButton не подходит под мою задачу, так как мне нужно чтобы можно было выключить все кнопки обратно. Я пробовал хранить прошлую нажатую кнопку и выключать её когда включается другая, но тогда метки не правильно отображались (если надо, то приложу код с этим вариантом)

Вот код, filters это список инициализированных кнопок:

```
val filters = listOf(filter1, filter2, filter3, filter4, filter5)
val filterValues =
    mapOf(filter1 to 4L, filter2 to 2L, filter3 to 1L, filter4 to 5L, filter5 to 6L)


filters.forEach { filter ->
    filter.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->
        clusterizedCollection.clear()
        visibleIds.clear()
        if (isChecked) {
            visibleIds.add(filterValues[filter]!!)
        } else {
            visibleIds.addAll(listOf(1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 6L))
        }
        updateMarkers()
    }
}
```

UPD:
Как уже было сказано, пробовал хранить предыдущую нажатую кнопку (lastChecked) и отключать её, пробовал много способов, но примерно суть была везде одна
В данном коде проблема в том, что если активировать новую кнопку, то прошлая кнопка деактивируется, но метки выведутся неправильно (их отображается в два раза больше)

```
filters.forEach { filter ->
    filter.setOnCheckedChangeListener { _, isChecked ->
        if (isChecked) {
            if (lastCheckedFilter != null && lastCheckedFilter != filter) {
                lastCheckedFilter?.isChecked = false
            }
            lastCheckedFilter = filter
            visibleIds.clear()
            visibleIds.add(filterValues[filter]!!)
        } else {
            visibleIds.addAll(listOf(1L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 6L))

        }
        clusterizedCollection.clear()
        updateMarkers()
    }
}
```

Comment: Переключатели для взаимоисключающих фильтров, имхо, будут выглядеть нелогично. Для RadioButton просто добавьте ещё одну, отключающую все фильтры и активируйте её по-умолчанию.

Comment: RadioButton это как последний вариант, всё таки ToggleButton предпочтительней, так как по дизайну нет дефолтной кнопки, иначе бы не задавал этого вопроса

Comment: Проблема добавить что ли? Ну тогда покажите свою реализацию, посмотрим что с ней не так.

Comment: Дополнил описание

Comment: Ну так а симптомы то какие, с чем бороться? Я правильно понимаю, что при выключении предыдущей кнопки срабатывает её слушатель и на этом всё ломается? Насколько я помню эта проблема решалась заменой `OnCheckedChangeListener` на обычный `OnClickListener` с ручной установкой состояния

Comment: Исправил еще раз, нашел код который работает более стабильно, описал в чем проблема. Вообще лучше всех работает первый код, где нет выключения предыдущей кнопки, там хотя бы в метках на карте проблем нет. По поводу OnClickListener, на сколько я понимаю, из-за него же не будет видно какая кнопка сейчас нажата (со стороны пользователя думаю будет путаница).

Comment: В итоге  с OnClickListener работает как надо :) Спасибо за подсказку что ли @woesss)

Answer (score 0):

Заменить .setOnCheckedChangeListener на .setOnClickListener